# Application gets crashed

Tags: iphone, facebook, share

I am using below code for auto share on facebook in my iPhone application, but my application get crashed with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message, when i tap share button.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
[variables setObject:@"Yours content to be shared" forKey:@"message"];
// share prepared content to fb
fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: check out did you get data in variables?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your code provided, but one idea:
Your dictionary `variables` is created as an autorelease object. This means if it is not retained in `fbGraph`, it will be deallocated as soon as the app returns to the main run loop, in which tabbing the share button is handled. In this case, `variables` no longer exists after the button is pressed, and you will get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
If you were using ARC, this will handled correctly by the compiler.